# Firebase Console Messaging when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a JSON in notification body in Firebase Console not api, and then convert in it in 
onMessageReceived method. This approach is working when app is in foreground, when app is in background, onMessageReceived method is not get called and notification body is shown as string in notification tray.

Is there any way or workaround for this?

Note: I am sending through console because of the Targeting feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) official docs

> *onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:*
>
> Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

That means, the notification will by default be shown by android system, you can't do nothing about that. But You can attach key-value data payload with your notification, which will be delivered as intent extras of of activity. You can receive those data values and do whatever you want to do.

I have created a helper function like below and put it inside `onCreate()` of the activity

```
public void FCM()
    {
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            String pack=(String) getIntent().getExtras().get(YOUR_KEY);
            if(pack!=null) {

                Log.e("fcm main pack", pack);
                try {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + pack);
                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                   
                    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + pack)));
                }
            }



        }
        //else Log.e("fcm main","null");
    }
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: Got it, just one thing , can we change logo of default notification, because it is showing white icon

Comment: @HarpreetSingh yes you can as far as i can tell....try this snippet, in AndroidManifest.xml inside `<application>` : `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>`

as it has solved the problem, you might as well accept the anwer

Answer (score 0):

from console it adds `"notification"` in notification data and when app is in background firebase handles `"notification"` data by itself. Even you have any additional data in `"data"` object! that will not accessible for you.

So from console you can't trigger `onMessageReceived()` you have to send push manually by removing `"notification"` data to trigger  `onMessageReceived()` when app is in background

like this

```
{
 "to":"/topics/topic_name",//or token id of specified user

"data" : {
  "x" : "true",
  "y" : "Abc",
  "z" : "123"
  }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to change in system generated notification like icon you can add this in your `manifest.xml` file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/google_blue" />
```

Comment: You mean to say i have to send via FCM api? But by that, i can't use targeting feature.

Comment: yes you have to use FCM Api ... console is only for testing ...
you can implement any other logic for targeting

Comment: I'm using FCM api from 2 years to get rid of this problem ... as @Touhidul Islam answer is stating that `In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.` so you can't change notification style and implementation and you can only get that extra data when user will click on notification and application will be in foreground again

Comment: Got it, just one thing , can we change logo of default notification, because it is showing white icon